# Flutter Handling Debug Console Errors 'Method not found'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

While following a Flutter course on Firebase, I tried to reload my emulator. Although the app works fine, I received some error log in the debug console:

```
/EGL_emulation(20277): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe97df060: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe4bddba0)
D/eglCodecCommon(20277): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
Restarted application in 5 876ms.
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found // HERE
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found // HERE, and
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found // HERE
Error handling 'checkPlatformOverride' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.platformOverride
Error handling 'serviceExtension' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.inspector.setPubRootDirectories
Error handling 'checkIsWidgetCreationTracked' custom request: method not available: ext.flutter.inspector.isWidgetCreationTracked
```

Having never encountered such errors, I would like to understand why this happened and how to fix them.

Comment: Are you using Firebase messaging?

Comment: @AliAlizadeh No, just testing the anonymous authentification.

Comment: I guess there is no one with the same problem as we are.
Good luck on your journey.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I have the same problem. I also use firebase. I recently did a firebase auth update. What version are you on?

Comment: @MikeOttink Hi Mike, I am sorry this happened to you, try downgrading to a stable version of Flutter. Check solution below.

Comment: @MikeOttink I just re-edited the answer.

Comment: I appears to resolve my issue

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading Flutter version to a stable one by doing this in Terminal/Command Line:

```
flutter channel stable
```

I still do not know what was the problem though.

Answer (score 6):

Stoping the app and cleaning helped me. Try to stop app and run in the terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by repairing the pub cache.

flutter pub cache repair